# Unable to get stable set of rows

Tags: oracle, merge

I am trying to update latitude/longitude where missing using a merge statement. It errors: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables. I thought that meant that the inner query matched more than one record in the outer table. I do not see how this query could produce that problem:

```
merge into people a using (
select address, city, state, zip,
max(latitude) latitude,
min(longitude) longitude
from people where latitude>0 and longitude<0
and address is not null
and city is not null
and state is not null
and zip is not null
group by address, city, state, zip
) b on (a.address=b.address and a.city=b.city and a.state=b.state and a.zip=b.zip)
when matched then update
set a.latitude=b.latitude, a.longitude=b.longitude
```

As you can see, I've ensured that none of the keys I'm matching on are allowed to be null. I'm grouping by them to ensure I get one and only one row for each unique set of values. So, I don't see how I could get more than one match on the join.